# How to prevent record duplication when working with a NHibernate Element?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums

We have a `RealEstateFile` entity that has a list of usages and usages are **`Enum`** so we had to map them as an `Element` like this :

```
<bag cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="join" lazy="false" name="Usage">
  <key>
    <column name="RealEstateFile_id" />
  </key>
  <element type="DataDefinition.Enum.RealEstateFileEnums.Usages,
                 DataDefinition, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <column name="Usages" />
  </element>
</bag>
```

now every time we run a query we get one usage per query record for example if a file only has one usage defined and we run a query that returns two records `NHibernate` returns a file that has two usages that are actually the same.

I know that this happens because `NHibernate` does not any way to find out equality for `Enum` types (The table has no `Id`).

I'd like to know how can I define an element to solve the duplication problem for `Elements`?

Answer (score 2):

If the collection `Usage` should contain only unique elements, and there is no ordering requirement, then the collection should be typed and mapped as an **`ISet<T>`**.

Comment: So simple but yet so forgettable :)